# Entity framework object not updating after being passed around

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, ninject, .net-4.5

I'm working on setting up a new MVC payment site with a dependency-injected database connection in a separate project, and experimenting with some new things as I do.  Currently, I'm trying to load an existing transaction from the database, authorize the card payment, and then save the result back to the database.  Simple and straightforward, but when I call `SaveChanges()`, nothing gets saved, and I've run out of things to try.

The database interaction for this is handled by a `CheckoutDataProvider`:

```
public class CheckoutDataProvider : ICheckoutDataProvider
{
    private readonly CheckoutEntities _context;

    public CheckoutDataProvider(CheckoutEntities _context)
    {
        this._context = _context;
    }



    public ITransaction GetTransactionDetails(Guid transactionId)
    {
        var trans = _context.Transactions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CheckoutTransactionId == transactionId);
        return trans; // It's OK if trans == null, because the caller will expect that.

    }

    public void AddAuthorization(ITransaction  transaction, IAuthorizationHistory history)
    {
        try
        {
            var trans = (Transaction)transaction;
            var hist = (AuthorizationHistory)history;
            trans.AuthorizationHistories.Add(hist);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidDataException(ex.EntityValidationErrors.First().ValidationErrors.First().ErrorMessage, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

`Transaction` and `AuthorizationHistory` are EF objects and correspond directly to the database tables.  `CheckoutEntities` is the context, as injected by Ninject.

`GetTransactionDetails()` works flawlessly.  I give it the transactionId, I get the object, and then I use that data to run the card and generate the `AuthorizationHistory` class.  Then I call `AddAuthorization()` to attach it to the transaction and save it to the database.  But both the new `AuthorizationHistory` object and any changes to the original `Transaction` fail to save.

I can tell from inspecting the `_context` object that it's not aware of any changes, and if I make changes withing `GetTransactionDetails()` (before it gets returned as an interface) they *will* persist.  So it looks like a problem with the casting (which makes me feel icky anyway, so I'd love to find out that that's the problem).

Am I missing something obvious?  Is there something missing to get this to work?  Is there a way to avoid the casting in `AddAuthorization()`?

Comment: Are you sharing the same DbContext instance for getTransactionDetails and AddAuthorization ?

Comment: @MarcCals - I don't know enough about how Ninject works to answer that.  I'm definitely storing the context on the provider, but I'm not sure that I'm actually using the same instance of the provider for both calls... which would lead to two separate contexts.  I'll investigate.

Comment: @MarcCals - Each call *does* come in from a different class which has `ICheckoutProvider` injected into it.  So I suppose it's possible that each of those classes gets a separate instance of the provider, and thus a separate context.  Is there a way to tell for sure, or to force either the provider or the context to be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are not sharing the same DBContext Between GetTransactionDetails and AddAuthoritzation. Due to this reason Entity Framework is not able to track the changes.

Set the scope life of DBContext for web request, you can do it with Ninject with `.InRequestScope()` https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes , with this option the same DBContext will be used during a web request.

Comment: That was it.  Nice and obvious once you know to ask the right questions.  Thank you!